# How can I plot a growing data file in real-time with matplotlib?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot, in real-time, a file (`datos.txt`) that will continuously get new data from a pH sensor.

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004818/2292702), I was able to plot a data file, but I'm still unable to do it in real time. I'm using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np    

# Converter function
datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))

# Read data from 'file.dat'
dates, levels = np.genfromtxt('/home/ramiro/Programas/pythonProgs/datos.txt',    # Data to be read
                              delimiter=19,  # First column is 19 characters wide
                              converters={0: datefunc}, # Formatting of column 0
                              dtype=float,   # All values are floats
                              unpack=True)   # Unpack to several variables

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Configure x-ticks
ax.set_xticks(dates) # Tickmark + label at every plotted point
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))

ax.locator_params(axis='x',nbins=10)
ax.plot_date(dates, levels, ls='-', marker='o')
ax.set_title('Hora')
ax.set_ylabel('pH')
ax.grid(True)

# Format the x-axis for dates (label formatting, rotation)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I have seen some examples of real-time plotting, but I can't figure out how to make mine work

Comment: There is [a question about plotting csv data in real time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922016/creating-a-live-plot-of-csv-data-with-matplotlib). Please tell us in how far it does not solve the issue. Be specific in your question. What exactly to you want to achieve? How should updated data be plotted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your plot into an `animate` function as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np    

def animate(i, fig, ax):
    # Converter function
    datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))

    # Read data from 'file.dat'
    dates, levels = np.genfromtxt('/home/ramiro/Programas/pythonProgs/datos.txt',    # Data to be read
                                  delimiter=19,  # First column is 19 characters wide
                                  converters={0: datefunc}, # Formatting of column 0
                                  dtype=float,   # All values are floats
                                  unpack=True)   # Unpack to several variables

    # Configure x-ticks
    ax.set_xticks(dates) # Tickmark + label at every plotted point
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))

    ax.locator_params(axis='x',nbins=10)
    ax.plot_date(dates, levels, 'k', ls='-', marker='o')
    ax.set_title('Hora')
    ax.set_ylabel('pH')
    ax.grid(True)

    # Format the x-axis for dates (label formatting, rotation)
    fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
    fig.tight_layout()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(fig, ax), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

This would reread and display your plot every second.